# Classpath file directory root (.classpath) in Spring-Boot project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to add a dependency manually inside `.classpath` file of my `Spring-Boot` project, but I can't find that file. Could you please tell me where the route is?

This is my project structure:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it's located at the root of your project (and modules) and it's a generated file, you don't edit it, you edit pom.xml instead.

Comment: I need customization on this file so I  need to change it manually not by pom.xml file. and also I can't see it in my project (module) root.

Comment: you don't edit it, you don't customize it, since it's generated